# Unity Issue with Vector3 and Transform

Tags: c#, unity

I am currently running into this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Vector3` to `Unity.Engine.Transform`

I am not sure on how to fix this issue because, here's the code where the issue is occurring.

```
target = pickedNumber.transform.position;
ball.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
```

Here's the `for` loop that contains the above snippet:

```
float waitTime = 8;
    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime * 2;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
        //Finding Game Objects
        numbers = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("num");
        ball = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ball");

        //Picking the random cube
        index = Random.Range (0, numbers.Length);
        pickedNumber = numbers [index];

        //Moving ball to cube
        target = pickedNumber.transform.position;
        ball.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);

        //Pause here
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);

        //Ball Returns to position
        ball.transform.position = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *target* is a transform, you want it to be `target = pickedNumber.transform;`, (no transform.**position**).

<s>If *target* is a Vector3, you want the next line to be `ball.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, step);`, (no target.**position**).</s>

I assume it's the first one, because of the wording of the error, but the second one is to show that it could be fixed another way.

Comment: That didn't work still getting the same issue with a new one about overloading the function. The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Vector3.MoveTowards(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, float)' has some invalid arguments
and   Argument `#2' cannot convert `UnityEngine.Transform' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector3

Comment: Only make one of those changes. If *target* is a transform, you still need "target.position" in the second line. I'll edit to make it more clear.